# Changing the style of options inside selectbox

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

as you can see from the title, to change the options box inside the selection box, I gave class to the option elements but they didn't change. The field I want to change is exactly here, but that field remains as default.

[image]

I want to change the option field inside the selection box. Specifically, I would like to point out that I want to change the option box, not the selectbox. When I searched, I saw that only css was written for the select box. My codes are written with tailwindcss, but any answer that leads to a solution is fine for me. Thank you everyone in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="countries" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg block p-2.5">
  <option selected="">Choose a country</option>
  <option class="text-3xl" value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It [seems to work](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/JjZXmxw). I made France slightly red. What is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: It doesn't work for me unfortunately. The field I want to change is the options field, but that field remains as default. I am attaching an image for your better understanding.

Comment: Oh, I see the image in your question. I now understand it: you want the set of options to change. One moment...

Comment: OK, the official line is that the `<select>` element is [notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css). I use a Javascript library that replaces the select, that is still in my HTML code, with other tags, which I can style. In my case it is [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/). Perhaps there is something, like this, you can use, that enables you to style the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate a select box and style it the way you want.

```js
const sel = document.querySelector("#selected");
/* Create an array with the options */
const opt = [...document.querySelectorAll(".option")];
const inp = document.querySelector("#sel");

sel.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const opts = document.querySelector("#options");
  if (opts.classList.contains("open")) {
    /* If the <ul> is visible, hide it */
    opts.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    /* If the <ul> is hidden, show it */
    opts.classList.add("open");
  }
});

opt.forEach((e, i, o) => {
  /* Add an event listener for each option */
  o[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    /* Store the value of the option in a variable */
    const chosen = e.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
    const opts = document.querySelector("#options");
    /* Assign the value of the option to the select box */
    sel.innerHTML = chosen;
    /* Assign the value of the option to the hidden input field */
    inp.value = chosen;
    /* And close the <ul> */
    opts.classList.remove("open");
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

#selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

#options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="selected">Select an option</div>
    <ul id="options">
      <li class="option"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```